# String Manipulation for retrieving two string from One String

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as:

```java
String identifier ="fmt{value}";
```

now I need a way to manipulate this string a get two strings from  identifier

```java
String format="fmt";
String value="value";
```

Any regex or native Java code to manipulate.

Comment: Yes,there are.You can do it.

Comment: can fmt and / or value themselves contain braces?

Comment: fmt and value cannot contain braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String identifier ="fmt{value}";
    String s[] = identifier.split("\\{|\\}");           
    System.out.println(s[0]);
    System.out.println(s[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this,It may help you

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Sample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String identifier = "fmt{value}";
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(identifier, "{}");

    System.out.println("---- Split by {} ------");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        System.out.println(st.nextElement());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try using `split()`

```
    String identifier = "fmt{value}";
    String format = identifier.split("\\{")[0];
    String value = identifier.split("\\{")[1].split("\\}")[0];
    System.out.println(format+"      " +value);
```

*Output:*

```
fmt      value
```

Comment: that is computationally quite expensive: `split` is not cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public void testSplit() {
    String identifier ="fmt{value}";
    String[] result = identifier.split("\\{|\\}");
    for(String s: result) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to do it with regex.

```
 Pattern pattern;
 Matcher matcher;
 pattern = Pattern.compile("");//here your regex
 matcher = pattern.matcher(identifier);
 while(matcher.find()) {
     //here your result
 }
```

have fun :)

Comment: Can you just elaborate it with exact regular expression. I don't think this will work as it will look only for one pattern. and will return string split by that single expression.

Comment: you can use 2 regex if you want to. if fmt is a number and value an other number you could use the same regex. depending what your format and value look like